# After doing a git commit, how do I see what was changed?

Tags: git

After doing a git commit, how do i see what was changed in the files commited? it says 5 insertions and 5 deletions. I want to be able to display that on the screen to see what they were.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you commit you can do `git diff --staged` this will show you the changes that you will be committing.  IMO, you should be doing this to make sure that you are only committing changes that you want.

Once you have committed, there are a couple of ways to see the changes:

```
git log -p -1
```

This will show the last commit along with the changes that were made in the commit.  The `-p` option tells the log to show the patch for the commit.  Adding a `-1` says to only show one commit (you can change this to any number of commits you want to see.

If you want to see the differences between your current state and the last commit you can do:

```
git diff HEAD~
```

`HEAD~` tells git to use the commit closest to the current state of your repo.

Comment: what does the -p and -1 stand for ? and HEAD~?

Comment: You can also do `git show HEAD`. @ducks: Try `git log --help` and `git diff --help`. (`git log -1` can also be written as `git log -n 1`.)